# Godog pass arguments/state between steps

Tags: go, concurrency, cucumber, gherkin

To comply with the concurrency requirements, I'm wondering how to pass arguments or a state between multiple steps in `Godog`.

```
func FeatureContext(s *godog.Suite) {
    // This step is called in background
    s.Step(`^I work with "([^"]*)" entities`, iWorkWithEntities)
    // This step should know about the type of entity
    s.Step(`^I run the "([^"]*)" mutation with the arguments:$`, iRunTheMutationWithTheArguments)
```

The only idea which comes to my mind is to inline the called function:

```
state := make(map[string]string, 0)
s.Step(`^I work with "([^"]*)" entities`, func(entityName string) error {
    return iWorkWithEntities(entityName, state)
})
s.Step(`^I run the "([^"]*)" mutation with the arguments:$`, func(mutationName string, args *messages.PickleStepArgument_PickleTable) error {
    return iRunTheMutationWithTheArguments(mutationName, args, state)
})
```

But this feels a bit like a workaround. Is there any feature in the `Godog` library itself to pass those information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Godog doesn't currently have a feature like this, but what I've done in the past in general (would need to be tested for concurrency) would be to create a TestContext struct to store data in and create a fresh one before each Scenario.

```golang
func FeatureContext(s *godog.Suite) {
    config := config.NewConfig()
    context := NewTestContext(config)

    t := &tester{
        TestContext: context,
    }

    s.BeforeScenario(func(interface{}) {
        // reset context between scenarios to avoid
        // cross contamination of data
        context = NewTestContext(config)
    })
}
```

I have a link to an old example here as well: https://github.com/jaysonesmith/godog-baseline-example

Comment: I had to search for a moment to understand the idea, but [this](https://github.com/jaysonesmith/godog-baseline-example/blob/master/godog_baseline_example_test.go) file explained it for me. Interesting approach, I like the object orientation aspect introduced here, limiting the available methods to those which make sense in the given context. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! Also, to folks who read this, the answer by @smikulcik is also a similar approach.

Answer (score 3):

I've found good luck using methods instead of functions for the steps. Then, putting state in the struct.

```
func FeatureContext(s *godog.Suite) {
    t := NewTestRunner()

    s.Step(`^I work with "([^"]*)" entities`, t.iWorkWithEntities)
}

type TestRunner struct {
    State map[string]interface{}
}

func (t *TestRunner) iWorkWithEntities(s string) error {
    t.State["entities"] = s
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually quite similar to Jayson Smith's solution, but the code snippet is more explicit!

Answer (score 2):

Latest version (v0.12.0+) of `godog` allows chaining `context.Context` between hooks and steps.

You can have `context.Context` as step definition argument and return, test runner will provide context from previous step as input and use returned context to pass to next hooks and steps.

```
func iEat(ctx context.Context, arg1 int) context.Context {
    if v, ok := ctx.Value(eatKey{}).int; ok {
        // Eat v from context.
    }
    // Eat arg1.
    
    return context.WithValue(ctx, eatKey{}, 0)
}
```

Additional information and examples: https://github.com/cucumber/godog/blob/main/release-notes/v0.12.0.md#contextualized-hooks.